# Selenium IDE: Call a different Test to run within a series of test as part of a command

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a test in Selenium IDE that check if an element is present. In the current case im checking if the site is in french before running other test. Is it possible to call this test to run from within a different test without having to copy paste all of the lines in every test I run? what I mean to do is similar to...

StartMyTest

Command1 / RunMyLanguageCheckTest

Command2

Command3

Command4

End

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can call other tests in selenium-ide but what you can do is run `gotoIf` to see if the site is in french and then run the tests

```
<tr>
    <td>storeElementPresent</td>
    <td>LANGUAGE IDENTIFIER</td>
    <td>isPresent</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>${isPresent} == false</td>
    <td>NotFrench</td>
</tr>
INSERT TESTS HERE
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>NotFrench</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Once filled out this test will check to see if the page is in french `(true)` and run the tests. If it isn't in french `(false)` it will jump to the label `NotFrench` and continue with the test case.

If you want the test to hard fail if it is in french then I use some code like this.

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>Page is in french</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

It will fail when it tries to click `Page is in french` and that will appear in the log so you can diagnose the problem.

Comment: That's what I did so far but my employer wants it to be even simplier. Thanks still for answering. We did try to do it as an XML script but it didn't work either.

Comment: Do you have an element that defines the page as being in french?